# Highcharts - show at least 5 horizontal grid lines, even when value doesn't change

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart, in which I want to show only y grid lines. Hovewer, when value is constant for some longer period of time (chart shows only last 5 ticks), all grid lines disappear. Is it possible to always show multiple vertical grid lines, even when value is the same for all x's?

How it looks right now:
[image: how it looks right now]

How I want to make it look like:
[image: should look like this]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [tickAmount](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/tickamount/) to tell the amount of ticks that you want.

Also you can create your own tick position logic, creating ticks whenever you want with [tickPositioner](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/xaxis/tickpositions-tickpositioner/).

And also you can tune some tick options to finally fit your likings with all the `*tick*` options Highcharts has: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis. Just search for the `tick` word and look after `yAxis...` or read all the options one by one.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to achieve what you seek would be to set a `min` and `max` for the `yAxis`, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/h0yrcuse/), like so:

```
yAxis: {
    gridLineWidth: 2,
    min: 1,
    max: 5
}
```

A softMin and softMax could potentially make it look nicer. [Highcharts API on softMin](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.softMin).

Comment: nice solution, but I really like the fact, that highcharst can auto tune it's scale. Can I somehow achieve multiple lines, with auto adjusting min and max? It's hard to tell min and max for me, because it may change, with every new tick.

Comment: @bartosz.baczek Check my answer. Is exactly what you ask.

Comment: Yep, your reference to Highcharts API helped me, I believe you should update your code snippet and fiddle to use softMin & softMax instead of min & max :)